# Trying to convert Point B LLA into an ECEF from the perspective of Point A LLA

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation, augmented-reality, cartesian-coordinates

Given:

- LLA point A
- LLA Point B
- Heading of point A
- Heading of Point B

Problem:

> Given the info above, I have the Geolocation (lat, long) and headings
> of two points, point A and point B. Based on those two sets of
> geolocations, I want to convert the location of point B into an
> [x,y,z] ECEF coordinate on a cartesian plane from the perspective of
> point A being [0,0,0] . The goal is to render an object in space using
> AR.

Desired outcome would look similar this: https://github.com/ProjectDent/ARKit-CoreLocation
Im looking to do this in pure Javascript/react if possible. Ive found alot of math that lets me find the distance between two geolocations points but not the conversion of a point to ECEF coordinates from the perspective of another coordinate.